# Make a Service call when app is not running iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have one requirement that when user submit a form. I have to give user 30 minute time gap to edit the form. If he don't edit the form in 30 minute time interval , the form should be automatically submitted even if the app is not running. Can we make a service call when app is not at all running? If yes then how to do this. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on Jasmeet's answer, you will need to change the server. You will need to submit the form at the latest in `applicationDidEnterBackground:`, though you may want to submit it much sooner than that (since the app may crash or the phone may be turned off, in which case you will never go into the background). If there are edits made, then you would submit the form again. If 30 minutes pass (as measured by the server), then the server will accept the form. You will likely want to include some timestamp information in the request so the server knows when the form was last edited.

There is no way to run code at an arbitrary time on the device. You must change the server code, or you cannot solve this problem. (Even if there were a way to run code at an arbitrary time on the device, it would not solve your problem, since the device may not even be turned on or have network access 30 minutes later.)

If you cannot change the server for some reason, then you will have to change your requirements. This cannot be solved as you describe it.

Comment: Thanks Rob... I will definitely look in the server side implementation.

Comment: Rob, are you suggesting to submit each time the form is edited and each time the app enters background until 30 minutes have passed?  What about that can't be controlled entirely by the client?

Comment: Actually I'm saying to submit each time the form is edited, having nothing to do with "until 30 minutes have passed." Let the server decide which edits to commit and which ones to coalesce. As a more complex solution, the app could submit after 30 minutes if it stays in the foreground that whole time, and proactively submit when going into the background (along with some timestamp of how long it's been). Less server traffic that way, but a lot more client code. Unless server traffic were a major issue, I'd do it the first way.

Comment: (BTW, this is exactly how I'm currently managing a location-tracking app. I just shovel everything to the server, and let the server figure out how to smooth/filter/etc the data. I let the client stay dumb and that gives us a lot more flexibility. Much easier to update the server than push a new client through app review to change an algorithm.)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to submit the form in background there might be chances the form will not submit if the app is suspended in the background.

you can submit a form first and if user edit the form within 30 min you can resubmit the form.

Comment: you can send the request in the background but might lost the data as you cannot ensure that request will go in the background.

Comment: Actually User can keep the app in background or they can kill the app. If it is in background then I can hit the service. But If user has killed the app then can we hit the services?

Comment: No, you do not send the request if app is killed. There are lot of scenario when your request does not go to server like if app is suspended by phone or phone get switched off.

Comment: If the user kills the app, you should not expect to run again for any reason until the user relaunches your app. If the system shuts you down for memory or because of a reboot, you often will be relaunched automatically in response to various situations (background refresh, location monitoring, etc), but if the user explicitly kills you, you should expect to stay down.

Answer (score 0):

If you submit the app with background mode enabled and handling your work without Apple guidelines for background mode support enabled. Your app will be rejected. Please review the background mode support guidelines before taking up the appdidenterbackground call working. You may prompt the user to fill the data but don't autosubmit rather autosave and next time he wake up just restore the form so he can continue to have a good user experience.

Apple Guidelines to use background mode.

```
2.5.4 Multitasking apps may only use background services for their 
intended purposes: VoIP, audio playback, location, task completion, 
local notifications, etc. If your app uses location background mode, 
include a reminder that doing so may dramatically decrease battery 
life.
```

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/